# How get code coverage on java production code with clojure unit tests?

Tags: java, testing, clojure

I got Java production code and unit tests written in Clojure. Is there a way of measuring the code coverage?

Is there an eclipse plugin for this? I use eclEmma for my Java unit tests, is there an similar one for tests written in Clojure?

Comment: If the code being tested is Java code, shouldn't any coverage tool for Java work?  You want coverage information on the Java code, right?

Answer (score 1):

I heard about this project in a ClojureWest talk, though have not used it my self. perhaps it would be worth looking into for this:

https://github.com/dgrnbrg/guzheng

```
"guzheng is a library for doing branch coverage analysis of clojure code."
```

it seems to have a lein plugin to make running it a bit smoother.